# Android Java service method is returning always same value to Qt Android service

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm trying to return value to Qt service from java service code. Java always returns initial value for variable. However when I run same code in Qt main activity, it is working.

Code in BackService java class:

```
public static int SAYK = 0;

public static void callNorm(int valSy) {
    BackService.SAYK = valSy;
    System.out.println("Result= "+BackService.SAYK);
}

public static int retStt() {
    return BackService.SAYK;
}
```

C++ code in Qt Service:

```
int jobj = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("org/qtproject/example_v2/BackService",
                                                     "retStt",
                                                     "()I");
```

When I call "callNorm" function from java, system prints new value of SAYK. But when I call "retStt" from Qt service, it returns only initial value 0. I tried also with callStaticObjectMethod, getStaticField, java native functions(gives unsatisfied link error) etc. Unfortunately, none of these worked. Also I can call java functions that has not return value from Qt Service, without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that android service was placed in same android sandbox with qt cpp app, and they are sharing memory. But actually i had in android manifest:

`<service android:process=":qt" android:name=".QtJavaService">`

What actually happens if you call static methods of Your Android Java Service you will get them from empty instance of the qt process, and the proper instance is in :qt process.

So you just need to remove "android:process=":qt" "